# local storage returning [object Object] in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to get an object called `userInfo` from localStorage which I had saved earlier during login in my Angular application. But Although the `localStorage.setItem()` is saving the data successfully in my local storage when trying to get it by `localStorage.getItem` instead of getting the full object I'm getting `[object Object]` in response.

productService.ts

```
  public setUserInfoInLocalStorage: any = (data) => {
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  public getUserInfoFromLocalStorage: any = () =>{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  }
```

component.ts

```
this.productService.setUserInfoInLocalStorage(apiResponse.data.userDetails);
console.log(this.productService.getUserInfoFromLocalStorage()); //getting  [object Object] instead of JSON
```

the full data I receive after login:

```
{"error":false,"message":"Login Successful","status":200,"data":{"authToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqd3RpZCI6IkNzeHdXeUJCTCIsImlhdCI6MTU5NzM3NTkzNzU3MCwiZXhwIjoxNTk3NDYyMzM3LCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoVG9rZW4iLCJpc3MiOiJhZG1pbi1ibG9nIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI5Q2dzNmlFeEUiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3QxQHRlc3QxLmNvbSIsImlzU2VsbGVyIjp0cnVlfX0.gp5N6HUdz0UIXpRKseTVV5yzfmj8098oesQDjf2mm6k","userDetails":{"userId":"9Cgs6iExE","email":"test1@test1.com","isSeller":true}}}
```

data after saving in local storage:

```
userInfo:"{"userId":"9Cgs6iExE","email":"test1@test1.com","isSeller":true}"
```

Comment: so, if you `console.log(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))` the output is a **string** in JSON format?

Comment: by the way, that data looks like invalid JSON

Comment: the output is ```[object Object]```

Comment: so, the problem is that its not setting the value correctly ... what's the output of `console.log('JSON.stringify(data))` if you put that code in the setUser.... function or better still `console.log(data)` in that function - because if you pass the string `"[object Object]"` to setUser.... function, that's what it will store - perhaps you're calling setUser.... wrong

Comment: it getting set in the ```userInfo``` key. But when I use ```console.log(localStorage.getItem())``` to view ```userInfo``` it's sending ```[object Object]``` instead of fetching the JSON.

Comment: so, the localStorage is being set to "object Object" ... so it's the setting that's the problem

Comment: How to set it properly then??

Comment: do it like this `console.log(JSON.strigify(this.productService.getUserInfoFromLocalStorage()));`

Comment: clearly you're sending `"[object Object]"` to the `setUserInfoInLocalStorage` function ... show how you are calling that function

Comment: Your local data storage looks like wrong. just console data before storing it in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

If `localStorage.getItem('key')` returned `[object Object]` instead of `String`:

1. Remove it by call `localStorage.removeItem('key')`.
2. Before code `localStorage.setItem('key', value)` , check `value` type if it `String` or `Object`, this problem not happen if `value` is `String`.

You can check type of variable by `console.log(typeof value);`